# OpenXML SDK- Worksheet throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I am using below code in order to retrieve data from excel file. And I notice that the Worksheet object of WorksheetPart throws null reference exception. Can any one tell me why this exception is thrown? Also what I can do in order to avoid this error?

```
SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("1.xlsx", true);
Sheet sheet = (Sheet)doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstOrDefault();
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)doc.WorkbookPart
                                                .GetPartById(sheet.Id);
Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet; // throws null reference exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not finding your `WorksheetPart` so when you try to access the `Worksheet` property it throws a null reference exception. Try getting your `WorksheetPart` this way where sheet name is the name of your worksheet:

```
string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>()
                                 .First(s => sheetName.Equals(s.Name))
                                 .Id;

WorksheetPart workSheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);
```

Comment: I tried the above code. It still throws the same null reference exception !